# how to clear inputs after click the submit in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i need to clear  inputs that user wrote it after clicking the submit button
i dont know which code i have to insert to my script to clear them

```html
<p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="person.name">
</p>
<p>last name: <input type="text" placeholder="last name" ng-model="person.Lname"></p>
<p>phone number: <input type="text" placeholder="number" ng-model="person.number"></p>
<button type="submit" ng-click="sabt()">submit</button>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>phone number</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in list">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.Lname}}</td>
        <td>{{x.number}}</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.list=[];
    $scope.person={};
    $scope.sabt = function(){
        $scope.list.push($scope.person);        
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.list=[];
    $scope.person={};
    $scope.sabt = function(){
        $scope.list.push($scope.person); 
        //CLEAR inputs
        $scope.person = {};       
    }       
});
```